using POSIXct to try and clean datetime cells in a table
I am trying to clean some tables in r and I have two columns that are in date time value. I know that date time value cells are difficult to deal with. Part of my problem is that the cells are mixed in the data - some are set up as 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm' and others are formatted as 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm' and I need all of them to be formatted as 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm' however I also tried to split them so that one has the date and one has the time. I run this code that I have and it executes without an issue and or an error code but the columns 'started_at_date' and 'started_at_time' are both showing as 'NA' values in the table values.
tc_2_df$started_at_time <- format(as.POSIXct(tc_2_df$'started_at', 
                                             "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",
                                             tz = "UTC",
                                             format = "%H:%M"))
tc_2_df$started_at_date <- format(as.Date(tc_2_df$'started_at',"%Y-%m-%d"),
                                  format = "%Y-%m-%d")

and here is the 'dput(head(tc_2_df))'
structure(list(ride_id = c("AE8C3C02D0A5DCF3", "A48FE08613B93786", 
"8E0FF571154B5CDC", "9F4FBBFAFBF6DAF8", "3079E649EFE9662A", "B059C3B3F5780661"
), rideable_type = c("electric_bike", "electric_bike", "classic_bike", 
"electric_bike", "electric_bike", "electric_bike"), started_at = c("7/6/2024 18:27", 
"6/6/2024 21:55", "2024-20-06 7:54", "2024-19-06 19:35", "2024-20-06 0:34", 
"2024-19-06 20:28"), ended_at = c("7/6/2024 18:27", "6/6/2024 21:59", 
"2024-20-06 7:55", "2024-19-06 19:57", "2024-20-06 0:46", "2024-19-06 20:46"
), start_station_name = c("N/A", "N/A", "Wood St & Chicago Ave", 
"N/A", "N/A", "N/A"), start_station_id = c("N/A", "N/A", "N/A", 
"N/A", "N/A", "N/A"), end_station_name = c("N/A", "N/A", "N/A", 
"N/A", "N/A", "N/A"), end_station_id = c("N/A", "N/A", "N/A", 
"N/A", "N/A", "N/A"), start_lat = c(41.93, 41.81, 41.8956, 41.81, 
41.81, 41.81), start_lng = c(-87.65, -87.61, -87.6721, -87.61, 
-87.61, -87.62), end_lat = c(41.93, 41.81, 41.8956, 41.81, 41.81, 
41.81), end_lng = c(-87.65, -87.62, -87.6721, -87.62, -87.61, 
-87.61), member_casual = c("member", "member", "member", "member", 
"member", "member"), started_at_time = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    started_at_date = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")


library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df |> 
  mutate(across(ends_with('_at'),
                ~parse_date_time(., c('m/d/Y H:M','Y-d-m H:M')))) |>
  # limiting reprex to print first few columns
  select(ride_id:ended_at)
#>            ride_id rideable_type          started_at            ended_at
#> 1 AE8C3C02D0A5DCF3 electric_bike 2024-07-06 18:27:00 2024-07-06 18:27:00
#> 2 A48FE08613B93786 electric_bike 2024-06-06 21:55:00 2024-06-06 21:59:00
#> 3 8E0FF571154B5CDC  classic_bike 2024-06-20 07:54:00 2024-06-20 07:55:00
#> 4 9F4FBBFAFBF6DAF8 electric_bike 2024-06-19 19:35:00 2024-06-19 19:57:00
#> 5 3079E649EFE9662A electric_bike 2024-06-20 00:34:00 2024-06-20 00:46:00
#> 6 B059C3B3F5780661 electric_bike 2024-06-19 20:28:00 2024-06-19 20:46:00

Created on 2024-07-17 with reprex v2.1.0

If you want to stay base R you can try as.POSIXct with several format strings. But since it's not vectorized we have to scan each date separately using sapply.
Assembling a function
getFormat <- function(dates) as.POSIXct(sapply(dates, \(x)
  na.omit(as.POSIXct(x, format=c("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M")))))

Note that we have to use as.POSIXct twice because otherwise the date class will fall back to numeric.

Apply function
transform(tc_2_df, 
  started_at = getFormat(started_at), ended_at = getFormat(ended_at))

output
           ride_id rideable_type          started_at            ended_at
1 AE8C3C02D0A5DCF3 electric_bike 2024-06-07 18:27:00 2024-06-07 18:27:00
2 A48FE08613B93786 electric_bike 2024-06-06 21:55:00 2024-06-06 21:59:00
3 8E0FF571154B5CDC  classic_bike 2024-06-20 07:54:00 2024-06-20 07:55:00
4 9F4FBBFAFBF6DAF8 electric_bike 2024-06-19 19:35:00 2024-06-19 19:57:00
5 3079E649EFE9662A electric_bike 2024-06-20 00:34:00 2024-06-20 00:46:00
6 B059C3B3F5780661 electric_bike 2024-06-19 20:28:00 2024-06-19 20:46:00
     start_station_name start_station_id end_station_name end_station_id
1                   N/A              N/A              N/A            N/A
2                   N/A              N/A              N/A            N/A
3 Wood St & Chicago Ave              N/A              N/A            N/A
4                   N/A              N/A              N/A            N/A
5                   N/A              N/A              N/A            N/A
6                   N/A              N/A              N/A            N/A
  start_lat start_lng end_lat  end_lng member_casual started_at_time
1   41.9300  -87.6500 41.9300 -87.6500        member            <NA>
2   41.8100  -87.6100 41.8100 -87.6200        member            <NA>
3   41.8956  -87.6721 41.8956 -87.6721        member            <NA>
4   41.8100  -87.6100 41.8100 -87.6200        member            <NA>
5   41.8100  -87.6100 41.8100 -87.6100        member            <NA>
6   41.8100  -87.6200 41.8100 -87.6100        member            <NA>
  started_at_date
1            <NA>
2            <NA>
3            <NA>
4            <NA>
5            <NA>
6            <NA>

